# HTML5 - how to detect a file is accessible

Tags: html, fileapi

In my app I upload a file to the server using HTML5 File API, however I am encountering a situation where a file is not accessible because it is being used by another process. This actually creates two different error conditions in firefox and in chrome. Is there a way to detect if a file is inaccessible using html5?

Comment: Have you looked the sample in this link which shows how you can read a file and in case of error you can write proper error handler: http://www.azoft.com/spotlight/2011/02/02/filesystem-apifile-api.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That will work, however currently I am not reading the file locally, only slicing it and sending it to the server. I was wondering if there's an API call to just check if it is readable without actually having to read it locally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked the sample in this link which shows how you can read a file and in case of error you can write proper error handler:

http://www.azoft.com/spotlight/2011/02/02/filesystem-apifile-api.html

About your second questions "if there's an API call to just check if it is readable without actually having to read it locally", I verified that there is no such API to just get the file handle state and verify it. I think it could be because (but i may be wrong):

- the web application runs on any box with limited privilege and getting file handle could require SYSTEM level access
- The file handle access could be different for different OS (Linux or Windows)

Comment: I had hoped to avoid reading the file (like in the sample) but eventually I do read it to find out if it accessible, thanks!